# SSLHandshakeException after calling setDefaultHostnameVerifier , Disable SSL verification

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to disable SSL's verification for hostnames with this code:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((a, b) -> true);
```

However, I still get a SSLHandshakeException requesting a file over HTTPs.

I've already tried to add the website certificate with keystore which didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

In almost all cases a handshake exception is unrelated to the validation of the certificate, but caused by unexpected protocol version, no shared ciphers, missing SNI extension, missing client certificate, weak DH key ....

This means it does not help to disable the hostname verification, which is a bad idea anyway because it is practically the same as disabling any kind of certificate validation: an attacker could just use any certificate signed by a trusted CA, no matter the hostname. Such a certificate is usually easy to get.

Comment: @JimmyT.: look at log files, debug messages, packet dumps, use tools like [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze) etc. SSL debugging is not trivial because you often get no useful error message. You might look at my [guide to SSL debugging](http://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html) and if you still need help  this guide also tells you which information you should provide when asking for help.